# distribute 2 users while payemt is success in paypal

Tags: php, payment-gateway, paypal

Distribute 2 users while payment is successful means if user pay $30  from my site

so i want to distribute 2 user means whatever paypal fee 1st user for $10 and 2nd for $10.

how i do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with [Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_adaptivepayments.pdf) or [Express Checkout](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ec).

If you want to hide the split from the payer you'll need to use Adaptive Payments, specifically a chained payment.  This is covered in various chapters in that PDF doc I linked you to.  It's done with the [Pay API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/pay-api-operation).

If you don't mind the payer seeing the split you can use a parallel payment, which is available in both Express Checkout and Adaptive Payments.

If a parallel payment is what you end up doing I would recommend you do it with Express Checkout because that API is more mature and provides you with more features.

Again, though, if you want to hide the split from the payer so they only see the primary receiver you'll need to use a chained payment which is only part of Adaptive Payments - Pay.